# Jpa - Two @OneToOne relations with same 'mappedBy'

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I have two java-classes / db-tables: 'message' and 'thirdparty'

```
@Entity
public class Message {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "message")
    private ThirdParty source = null;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "message")
    private ThirdParty target = null;

    ....
}

@Entity
public class ThirdParty {
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Message.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Message", referencedColumnName = "mess_id", nullable = false)
    private Message message = null;

    @Column(name = "isSource", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isSource = null;
}
```

Message has two references to ThirdParty, which could be differenced by isSource (if they are source or target).

This cannot be resolved by jpa they way it is designed / annotiated. But is there a way to to this by adding some annotiation or some kind of special sql-statement?

Comment: Is it possible for you to represent it as a **OneToMany** relationship with **ThirdParty** on the many side?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345203/multiple-manytoone-fields-pointing-to-same-entity-in-jpa-hibernate. It mentions a similar problem.

Comment: You can't have two OneToMany references pointing to the same entity having the same mappedBy

Answer (score 0):

This is conceptually wrong. You cannot do this. OneToOne mapping occurs when there are two entities mapped in the following way :
Entity1 : Has a primary key(PK1) and others along with a foreign key(FK)
Entity2 : Has a primary key (PK2).
Now the FK is mapped to PK2 in such a way that for each occurence of PK there must be a one and only one matching occurence of FK.