# @OneToMany and @ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I need to resolve  this problem:

```
@Entity
public class Team
{

    @OneToMany // how mapped it ?
    private List<Match> matches; // all played and coming matches
}

@Entity
public class Match
{

    @ManyToOne
    @Column( nullable = false )
    private Team teamA;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column( nullable = false )
    private Team teamB;
}
```

If I had one field like `Team team;` it would be easier by using `mappedBy = team;`.

I could use List teams instead of two fields and add @ManyToMany annotation, but it isn't good solution imho.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple @ManyToOne fields pointing to same entity in JPA / Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345203/multiple-manytoone-fields-pointing-to-same-entity-in-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: I saw it, but it isn't excatly this same problem. 

List<Match> matchesAsTeamA; +
List<Match> matchesAsTeamB;

instead of

List<Match>matches;

isn't logical ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you need to keep in mind that some matches are "at home" and some matches are "away". Thinking of it like that `homeTeam` and `awayTeam` will be easier than `teamA` and `teamB`.

Each team will have a `OneToMany` set of home matches and another `OneToMany` set for away matches. Then, you can add a convenience method to get all matches if want.

```
@Entity
public class Team {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="homeTeam")
    private Set<Match> homeMatches = new HashSet<>(); 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="awayTeam")
    private Set<Match> awayMatches = new HashSet<>(); 

    // getters and setters


    // special getter if you want it
    public Set<Match> getAllMatches() {
        Set<Match> allMatches = new HashSet<>(); 
        allMatches.addAll(homeMatches);
        allMatches.addAll(awayMatches);
        return allMatches;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Match {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "HOME_TEAM_ID", referencedColumnName = "TEAM_ID")
    private Team homeTeam;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AWAY_TEAM_ID", referencedColumnName = "TEAM_ID")
    private Team awayTeam;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Match table has a team_id (foreign key) primary key of the Team table. This code might help you. A tam has many matches and many teams are associated to one match.

In your Team entity :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Match> matches= []
```

In your Match entity :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")
Team team
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a fact that many matches can be associated to one team, and many teams (exactly 2) can be associated to a match.

Since you want one list with all matches the team is associated to without splitting into two mappings in team (for A or B) I would suggest that you use a @ManyToMany relation mapping between them.