# Hibernate mapping ManyToOne two times

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following in my model :
finished car

```
 private ObjectProperty<InMonter> inMonter = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

  @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "in_Monter_Id",referencedColumnName="inMonterId" )
public InMonter getInMonter() {
    return inMonter.get();
}

public ObjectProperty<InMonter> inMonterProperty() {
    return inMonter;
}

public void setInMonter(InMonter inMonter) {
    this.inMonter.set(inMonter);
}
```

monter:

```
private List<FinishedCar> fCar;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy ="inMonter")
public List<FinishedCar> getfCar() {
    return fCar;
}

public void setfCar(List<FinishedCar> fCar) {
    this.fCar = fCar;
}
```

What i want to accomplish is to have this mapping one more time like this :

```
private ObjectProperty<InMonter> outMonter = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
 @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "out_monter_id",referencedColumnName="inMonterId")
 public InMonter getMonterOut() {
    return outMonter.get();
}

public ObjectProperty<InMonter> monterOutProperty() {
    return outMonter;
}

public void setMonterOut(InMonter outMonter) {
    this.outMonter.set(outMonter);
}
```

and this

```
private List<FinishedCar> OutCar;
@OneToMany(mappedBy ="outMonter")
public List<FinishedCar> getOutCar() {
    return OutCar;
}

public void setOutCar(List<FinishedCar> OutCar) {
    this.OutCar = OutCar;
}
```

When i try to have two times this connection i get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.atlas.model.FinishedCar.outMonter in com.atlas.model.InMonter.outCar
```

But if i use just one ManyToOne annotation it works fine, i did not mix my annotations and i used AccesType.property on my class.

And according to this link [Multiple @ManyToOne fields pointing to same entity in JPA / Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345203/multiple-manytoone-fields-pointing-to-same-entity-in-jpa-hibernate) what i am trying to accomplish is possible, then why do i have an error ?

At the end : 
what i need is to have two monter fields in my finished car, but they both come from same Entity, named Monter. i could achive this by using different tables, but it mmakes no sense to do that.

Comment: do you have all the columns in your tables?

Comment: What do you mean ? all tables and columns are created by hibernate, so if mapping is ok i think there should be no problem

Comment: you want different columns in your database for inMonter and outMonter?

Comment: yes, i want that in my finishedCar entity i have column inMonter and outMonter. when i do this with one column it works, but with two i have issue

Comment: you should have a outMonter property in FinishedCar class. you have only InMonter.

Comment: what do you mean ? i have both, you can see in above code 
private ObjectProperty<InMonter> outMonter = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

private ObjectProperty<InMonter> inMonter = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

Comment: you should rename your entity to `Monter` and have a flag for in/out. or you create 2 entities which wouldn't make much sense

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate uses a getter name for property name (not a field name) in this situation.

```
@Entity
class FinishedCar {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "in_monter_id")
  public Monter getInMonter() {

  }

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "out_monter_id")
  public Monter getOutMonter() {

  }

}

@Entity
class Monter {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy ="inMonter")
  public List<FinishedCar> getfCar() {

  }

  @OneToMany(mappedBy ="outMonter")
  public List<FinishedCar> getOutCar() {

  }

}
```

Please, learn the Java Naming Convention and always (!) use it. You will have less problems in the future. For example, you shouldn't use field names like this: `OutCar`.

Also, try to understand how a property name corresponds to the getter and setter names. For example, you should have getter and setter to have a property.

Comment: Well, the only thing you have right about is that i used poor naming (but it was field that i just made real quick for testing).
Other than that, i used annotations on getters, as you can see in my original post, and i also used @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) for my Entity to explicitly show hibernate where to look for mappings. Can you help me in any other way please ? i agree i must sort out my naming properly, and i will then update my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Well i must thank v.ladynew and XtremeBaumer, for help.

First, i had issue that i did no use proper naming for my second field, and second i did not use @Column annotation for my id column, so hibernate would get confused , when i corrected those and started using Monter class instead InMonter class i managed to make it work :

example

```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy ="outMonter")
public List<FinishedCar> getFinishedCars() {
    return finishedCars;
}

public void setFinishedCars(List<FinishedCar> finishedCars) {
    this.finishedCars = finishedCars;
}
@OneToMany(mappedBy ="inMonter")
public List<FinishedCar> getFinishedCarsTest() {
    return finishedCarsTest;
}

public void setFinishedCarsTest(List<FinishedCar> finishedCarsTest) {
    this.finishedCarsTest = finishedCarsTest;
}
```

and

```
  @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="outMonterId",referencedColumnName = "monterId")
public Monter getOutMonter() {
    return outMonter.get();
}

   @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="inMonterId",referencedColumnName = "monterId")
public Monter getInMonter() {
    return inMonter.get();
}
```

How ever even though this mapping in itself is correct, it would not work untill i added @Column on my id field :

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="monterId")
public int getId() {
    return monterId.get();
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, because of without @Column you had `id` column, but referred `referencedColumnName = "monterId"`.