# JPA - How to map 2 @ManyToOne to the same parent Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `Profile` abstract entity and it has 2 children is `DoctorProfile` and `UserProfile`.

When an user book a doctor, it'll be saved in `Booking` entity.

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="profile_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Profile implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Gender gender;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DiscriminatorValue("DOC")
public class DoctorProfile extends Profile{
    private String title;
    private String addressTitle;
    private String address;
    private String workOffice;
    private float rateSummary;
    private BigDecimal basePrice;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DiscriminatorValue("PAT")
public class UserProfile extends Profile {
    private float weight;
    private float height;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Booking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id")
    private DoctorProfile doctorId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
    private UserProfile patientId;
    private Date dateTime;
    private BookStatus status;
    private String note;
    private boolean commentable;
    private String statusReason;
}
```

I'd like the code will be generate corresponding tables like this

[image]

What should I add to the entities to do that?

I've tried in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345203/multiple-manytoone-fields-pointing-to-same-entity-in-jpa-hibernate) but it doesn't work.
This is log info:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true
Removed for charaters limit

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

2019-04-06 23:35:21.503  INFO 15972 --- [           main] c.h.dbtoollib.DbToollibApplication       : Starting DbToollibApplication on DESKTOP-97KPL7R with PID 15972 (H:\HelloDoctor\db-toollib\target\classes started by khoa1 in H:\HelloDoctor)
2019-04-06 23:35:21.509  INFO 15972 --- [           main] c.h.dbtoollib.DbToollibApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-06 23:35:23.613  INFO 15972 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-04-06 23:35:23.693  INFO 15972 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 63ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-04-06 23:35:24.423  INFO 15972 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5bb6ebfe] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-04-06 23:35:24.940  INFO 15972 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-04-06 23:35:24.980  INFO 15972 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-04-06 23:35:24.980  INFO 15972 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
2019-04-06 23:35:24.992  INFO 15972 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6-preview\preview;C:\Program Files (x86)\VietPN;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\khoa1\Anaconda2;C:\Users\khoa1\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\khoa1\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Users\khoa1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\khoa1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\khoa1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\bin;;C:\Users\khoa1\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\khoa1\AppData\Roaming\npm;.]
2019-04-06 23:35:25.301  INFO 15972 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-04-06 23:35:25.302  INFO 15972 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3727 ms
2019-04-06 23:35:25.676  INFO 15972 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-04-06 23:35:25.863  INFO 15972 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-04-06 23:35:25.946  INFO 15972 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-04-06 23:35:26.076  INFO 15972 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
2019-04-06 23:35:26.078  INFO 15972 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-04-06 23:35:26.400  INFO 15972 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-04-06 23:35:26.535  INFO 15972 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-04-06 23:35:26.819  WARN 15972 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.hellodoctor.dbtoollib.entities.SnsKey
2019-04-06 23:35:26.819  WARN 15972 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.hellodoctor.dbtoollib.entities.SnsKey
2019-04-06 23:35:27.573  WARN 15972 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table booking add constraint FK9lhmqhfhg7xsc7663m7hmdqf4 foreign key (doctor_id) references profile (id)" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table booking add constraint FK9lhmqhfhg7xsc7663m7hmdqf4 foreign key (doctor_id) references profile (id)" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.hellodoctor.dbtoollib.DbToollibApplication.main(DbToollibApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: BLOB/TEXT column 'doctor_id' used in key specification without a key length
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:782) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:666) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

2019-04-06 23:35:27.577  WARN 15972 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table booking add constraint FK8mrj9ke8em51ig0shphd4lwsl foreign key (patient_id) references profile (id)" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table booking add constraint FK8mrj9ke8em51ig0shphd4lwsl foreign key (patient_id) references profile (id)" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.hellodoctor.dbtoollib.DbToollibApplication.main(DbToollibApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: BLOB/TEXT column 'patient_id' used in key specification without a key length
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:782) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:666) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

2019-04-06 23:35:28.384  INFO 15972 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-04-06 23:35:28.650  INFO 15972 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-04-06 23:35:28.695  WARN 15972 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-04-06 23:35:28.911  INFO 15972 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-04-06 23:35:28.914  INFO 15972 --- [           main] c.h.dbtoollib.DbToollibApplication       : Started DbToollibApplication in 7.998 seconds (JVM running for 10.319)
```

Comment: What's the concrete problem with the code you have? Where is the code of the Booking entity?

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated the post

Comment: Post the **complete** exception stack trace.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it right away

Comment: The exception shows that your patient_id column is of type BLOB instead of being of type bigint(20) as it should be. Fix (or drop) your schema.

Comment: OMG, Thank you so much! My bad...

Comment: Please add your answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception shows that your `patient_id` column is of type `BLOB` instead of being of type `bigint(20)` as it should be. Fix (or drop) your schema.